# WSO2APIM: APIs are failing with Error Message as - STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE =

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am using WSO2 APIM 2.5.0

I have recently started created/Onboarding APIs into APIM but seeing some issues in accessing them from store or from post.
For few of the API, it does not create any issue and it works absolutely fine. But for few of them I have getting below error:

```
INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = 
Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = 
/rest/abc/fun 
{org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

When I am checking the APIs, they donot have the anything dissimilar which points me that something missing in the not working API configuration.

I have checked the 
    /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/2.5.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-
    configs/default/endpoints and 
        /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/2.5.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse- 
    configs/default/api

Here is the response when I am trying to consume the API from postman:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
    <am:code>404</am:code>
    <am:type>Status report</am:type>
    <am:message>Not Found</am:message>
    <am:description>The requested resource is not available.
```

APIs are present as it should be. I am stuck here from long time now and not able to get any resolution.

Adding synapse file as well from usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/2.5.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
name="john.doe-AT-abc.com--FUNAPI"
context="/FUNAPI/3.0.0"
version="3.0.0"
version-type="context">
<resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/fun" faultSequence="fault">
 <inSequence>
<property name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"
expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"/>
<filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
<then>
<send>
<endpoint key="FUNAPI--v3.0.0_APIproductionEndpoint"/>
</send>
</then>
<else>
  <sequence key="_sandbox_key_error_"/>
</else>
</filter>
</inSequence>
<outSequence>
<class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.analytics.APIMgtResponseHandler"/>
<send/>
</outSequence>
</resource>
<handlers>
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.common.APIMgtLatencyStatsHandler"/>
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
<property name="apiImplementationType" value="ENDPOINT"/>
</handler>
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler">
<property name="RemoveOAuthHeadersFromOutMessage" value="true"/>
</handler>
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler"/>
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.analytics.APIMgtUsageHandler"/>
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.analytics.APIMgtGoogleAnalyticsTrackingHandler">
<property name="configKey" value="gov:/apimgt/statistics/ga-config.xml"/>
</handler>
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler"/>
</handlers>
 </api>
```

Request I am making from postman and below is the request form:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://xxx.xx.xx/api/funapifun/1.0.0/fun \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <tokenvalue>' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: xxx.xx.xx' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: e729-4c33-b3fc-3337cd63d691,c5cbadcd-dace-487d-9cc0- 
  8e833262905b' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
  -H 'content-length: 51' \
  -d '{
  "abc": "xxx",
  "cde": "iouiio"
    }'
```

Can someone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the API synapse file in `repository/deployment/server/synapse- configs/default/api/` and request you made.

Comment: @Bee: I got it working now. I was giving the production URL as http however when I replaced this to HTTPS and added certificate to it. It started working.. Not sure what was the issue

Comment: That shouldn't give you a 404 though. I can see your API's context has `3.0.0` and the request has `1.0.0`. Maybe it's a typo or you might have done the same mistake earlier.

Comment: yes thats a typo actually..